# How do i get rid of an "MySQLSyntaxErrorException"

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I'm currently building a little web-based tool using hibernate. I testrun the site in eclipse using a Tomcat v7.0 Server. My Database is using MySQL version 5.6 on Linux.

Now, everytime I run the program, starting my index.xhtml on the server, i get an outrageous error Message that looks like this:

```
ERROR: HHH000300: Could not complete schema validation
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'system_sequences' in information_schema
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor48.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.initSequences(DatabaseMetadata.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.<init>(DatabaseMetadata.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at com.ubs.tbt.database.KurseDAO.getModule(KurseDAO.java:139)
    at com.ubs.tbt.database.Klasse.module(Klasse.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:165)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:84)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getValue(UIRepeat.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:250)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:444)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.doVisitChildren(UIRepeat.java:679)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.visitTree(UIRepeat.java:637)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.visitTree(UITabPanel.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.visitTree(UIRepeat.java:643)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.saveView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:472)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:89)
    at javax.faces.application.StateManager.getViewState(StateManager.java:593)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderState(PartialViewContextImpl.java:454)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:417)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My hibernate.cfg

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.34:3306/BeurteilungsDB</property>
        <property name="connection.username">admin</property>
        <property name="connection.password">po2015</property>

        <!-- Zusaetzliche Hibernate-Properties -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <!-- Definition der gemappten Klassen -->

    <!--    <mapping class="ch.fg.bibliothek.Verlag" />-->
        <mapping class="com.ubs.tbt.database.Eventbewertung" />
        <mapping class="com.ubs.tbt.database.Modulbewertung" />
        <mapping class="com.ubs.tbt.database.Teilnehmer" />
        <mapping class="com.ubs.tbt.database.Klasse" />
        <mapping class="com.ubs.tbt.database.Firma" />
        <mapping class="com.ubs.tbt.database.Kursleiter" />
        <mapping class="com.ubs.tbt.database.Module" />
        <mapping class="com.ubs.tbt.database.Kurse" />

    </session-factory>


</hibernate-configuration>
```

The program itself runs normally and works the way its supposed to, but I'm having a hard time validating the rest of my console outputs, when this message is printed every second Line in the console.

Something worth mentioning is that I started receiving this message after adding the keyword `validate` at `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>`.

Where is this table supposed to be and most important, how do I get rid of this Message?

Comment: Try changing `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect` to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`. That could help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to understand the hibernate mapping to ddl, hbm2ddl.auto settings.

From the docs [**hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html):

> Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.
>   ***e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop***

`validate:` validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.

`update:` update the schema.

`create:` creates the schema, destroying previous data.

`create-drop:` drop the schema at the end of the session.

Your config fails to validate the schema as it can not find the `information_schema`.`system_sequences`. I think it is because the dialect you have chosen.

try to replace the  **org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect** with **org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect**

Look at doc url to pick the right dialect, and verify the rest of the config.

MySQL hibernate dialects:

```
MySQL               org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
MySQL with InnoDB   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
MySQL with MyISAM   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect
```

The `information_schema` is MySQL own information database. It contains all information about all the other (your own) databases that are maintained in its database server.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and all the information. I tried what you told me to and that kinda broke my programm. I would have to change my whole Database to match the requirements now. Is there a way around that?

Comment: how was your db created? did you use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to create first time? check what is in your mysql and verify it is ok. Otherwise you might need drop it and run with `create` flag. And later you might change it to `validate`. Remember this flags should be handled carefully in production env.

Answer (score -1):

Change  `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect` to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`.
In your application.properties you should have `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` It worked with MySQL Connector 8.